# Create a unique key based on the existing fields in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
Last Name   First Name         DATE        Total-Chrg
Jaime         KRiSH           5/1/2015    -4150.66
Jaime         KRiSH           5/1/2015     1043.66
Jaime         KRiSH           5/1/2015     1043.66
Jaime         KRiSH           5/1/2015      4150.66
Jaime         KRiSH           5/3/2015      4150.66
Peter         Jason           5/1/2015       321.02
Peter         Jason           5/1/2015       321.02
Peter         Jason           5/23/2015     123.02
```

I want the results to be in following way

```
Uniq ID    Last Name    First Name        DATE         Total-Chrg
1             Jaime       KRiSH           5/1/2015     -4150.66
2             Jaime       KRiSH           5/1/2015     1043.66
2             Jaime       KRiSH           5/1/2015     1043.66
3             Jaime       KRiSH           5/1/2015      4150.66
4             Jaime       KRiSH           5/3/2015      4150.66
5             Peter        Jason          5/1/2015       321.02
5             Peter        Jason          5/1/2015       321.02
7             Peter        Jason          5/23/2015     123.02
```

I basically need to create a Unique Key, as the table doesn't have any unique ID.

Comment: After you add your new field, the table will *still* not have a UNIQUE key.  You are simply creating a proxy for the existing natural-but-not-unique key (Last Name, First Name, DATE, Total-Chrg).  If you want the additional value to serve to "uniqueify" the records, the values should be 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1.

Comment: If you need a new field with a unique key, use a field with `uniqueidentifier` type and set its value by `NEWID()` - your `Uniq ID` is not unique and you can generate it in your queries ;).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working example,

Note you have a bug in your answer, the 7 should be a 6!!!

You basically have to make a table of distinct items. If this table has an Auto ID then SQL will make the key for you. You can then join the data back in and use the new key.

You can make this faster by putting an index on LastName,FirstName,Date and Total (on the temp table)

```
DECLARE @Data TABLE(LastName NVARCHAR(32),FirstName NVARCHAR(32),Date DATE,Total DECIMAL(18,4))
INSERT INTO @Data
VALUES
('Jaime','KRiSH','5/1/2015',-4150.66),
('Jaime','KRiSH','5/1/2015', 1043.66),
('Jaime','KRiSH','5/1/2015', 1043.66),
('Jaime','KRiSH','5/1/2015', 4150.66),
('Jaime','KRiSH','5/3/2015', 4150.66),
('Peter','Jason','5/1/2015', 321.02),
('Peter','Jason','5/1/2015', 321.02),
('Peter','Jason','5/23/2015',123.02)

CREATE TABLE #Temp (ID INT IDENTITY(1,1),FirstName NVARCHAR(32),LastName NVARCHAR(32),Date DATE,Total DECIMAL(18,4))
INSERT INTO #Temp (LastName,FirstName,Date,Total)
SELECT  LastName,
        FirstName,
        Date,
        Total

FROM        @Data
GROUP BY    FirstName,LastName,Date,Total

SELECT      T.ID,D.LastName,D.FirstName,D.Date,D.Total
FROM            @Data AS D
INNER JOIN  #Temp AS T ON T.LastName = D.LastName AND T.FirstName = D.FirstName AND T.Date = D.Date AND T.Total = D.Total

DROP TABLE #Temp
```

Answer (score 0):

You can assign one using `row_number()`:

```
select t.*, dense_rank() over (order by lastname, firstname, date, totalchrg)
from table t;
```

You can add an identity value:

```
alter table add column uniqueId identity(1, 1);
```

However, you have no control over which rows get which values.

Comment: I think it should be `DENSE_RANK`instead.

Comment: This is not correct,  ! he wants the same ID for some rows. This will give him 1 unique ID per row.    Re-read the question